# Sentence Structure and a Phrase - Are these sentences correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-structure

I havent learned english since 5 years, so I have joined an English lecture this year. I sometimes struggle with the sentence structure ...

Like this:

"Pandora, a moon the film is set on, ..." - Is this correct? In german it would be :D. Or is it better to say "The film is set on Pandora, a moon, ...

"If you want to know the result of this conflict ..."

"between ... and us, the humans" - "us the humans", can you say it like this? - "Result of this conflict ..." or is there any better way to say that, like outcome or ...?

Answer (score 0):

1) Pandora, a moon on which the film is set, is a tropical paradise.
This construction is a little more formal, because it avoids ending a clause with a preposition ("...is set on..."). The alternative that you suggest is also correct, and a little more direct. It depends on whether you want to start the sentence with Pandora or the film.

2)"Us, the humans" sounds weird, but you have written fragments that make it hard to know the full context, and therefore, the grammar that would be required. It's more likely that the pronoun "we" should be used: "We, the people of earth" or "We, as humans, have a responsibility..." for example. "Us" is for object form: "God gave the earth to us, his children, so that we could be fruitful and multiply." It's possible your sentence is correct, if the full meaning is like this: "The conflict between the martians and us, the human race, lasted for nearly a century."